# how to parse the gaps?

Tags: python, xpath, python-3.x, lxml

please help get prices from the pages of ebay.

in the following script, I get the prices from two specific pages.

```
import pprint
import requests
import lxml.etree
import lxml.html
import lxml.cssselect
import re


def get_doc(url):
    try:
        req = requests.get(url)
    except Exception:
        print('Error open. __', Exception)
    else:
        html = req.text
        doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
        return doc


for url in ['http://www.ebay.com/itm/DW-PDP-Concept-Pearlescent-White-Maple-Drumset-/121271668104?pt=US_Drums&hash=item1c3c5acd88', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/LOT-OF-20-DRUM-SET-TUNING-KEYS-DW-TAMA-PEARL-SABIAN-and-OTHER-UNIQUE-KEYS-/291092068092?pt=US_Drums&hash=item43c67076fc']:
    doc = get_doc(url)
    title = doc.xpath('//h1[@id="itemTitle"]/text()')
    priceUSD = doc.xpath('//span[@itemprop="price"]/text()')
    print(title, priceUSD)
```

the problem is that the price of the first page there is a space ('&_n_b_s_p_;'). therefore gets wrong xpath value text (). it looks as follows:

> ['DW/PDP Concept Pearlescent White Maple Drumset'] ['US $1\xa0200,00']
>   ['LOT OF 20 DRUM SET TUNING KEYS! DW! TAMA! PEARL! SABIAN! and OTHER
>   UNIQUE KEYS!!'] ['US $6,05']

p.s.
its no correct price: 'US $1\xa0200,00'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `\xa0`:

```
priceUSD = [t.replace('\xa0', '') for t in
            doc.xpath('//span[@itemprop="price"]/text()')]
```

BTW, I get following output without modification:

```
['DW/PDP Concept Pearlescent White Maple Drumset'] ['US $1,200.00']
['LOT OF 20 DRUM SET TUNING KEYS! DW! TAMA! PEARL! SABIAN! and OTHER UNIQUE KEYS!!'] ['US $6.05']
```

Comment: '//h1[@id="itemTitle"]/text()' => '//span[@itemprop="price"]/text()'

Comment: @Sergey, You're right. I copied wrong line from my local copy. Thanks.